# How to fix 'Max count' in the oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

Max count is not providing the correct value in Oracle Apex

```
SELECT  'TOTAL' label,
MAX(COUNT(REPORT_DATE )) value FROM DATA
Where STATUS = 'Open' 
  and MANAGED_BY = 'Internal' 
  and MANAGER = 'Vinod' 
  and SECOND_LEVEL_MANAGER = 'Kumar'
GROUP BY REPORT_DATE
```

Comment: What's exactly your question? What are you expecting to retrieve from this query? Is that being used in a report? in a chart? in an item? Please provide more information

Comment: Hi Higor, I want to highlight Total of this week count. REPORT_DATE has week on week data, hence I'm using max and count but this is fetching previous week rather than this week. I just need Max count of REPORT_DATE within one line

Answer (score 0):

Sample data would help; meanwhile, if I understood you correctly, I'd say that you need a `where` clause, not `group by`. Here's why: this is this month's calendar:

```
SQL> with calendar as
  2    (select trunc(sysdate, 'mm') + level - 1 datum
  3     from dual
  4     connect by level <= 31
  5    )
  6  select datum,
  7         to_char(datum, 'day', 'nls_date_language=english') day,
  8         to_char(datum, 'iw') week
  9  from calendar
 10  --where to_char(datum, 'iw') = to_char(sysdate, 'iw')
 11  order by datum;

DATUM      DAY                                  WE
---------- ------------------------------------ --
01.07.2019 monday                               27
02.07.2019 tuesday                              27
03.07.2019 wednesday                            27
04.07.2019 thursday                             27
05.07.2019 friday                               27
06.07.2019 saturday                             27
07.07.2019 sunday                               27
08.07.2019 monday                               28
09.07.2019 tuesday                              28
10.07.2019 wednesday                            28
11.07.2019 thursday                             28
12.07.2019 friday                               28
13.07.2019 saturday                             28
14.07.2019 sunday                               28
15.07.2019 monday                               29
16.07.2019 tuesday                              29
17.07.2019 wednesday                            29
18.07.2019 thursday                             29
19.07.2019 friday                               29
20.07.2019 saturday                             29
21.07.2019 sunday                               29
22.07.2019 monday                               30
23.07.2019 tuesday                              30
24.07.2019 wednesday                            30       --> today
25.07.2019 thursday                             30
26.07.2019 friday                               30
27.07.2019 saturday                             30
28.07.2019 sunday                               30
29.07.2019 monday                               31
30.07.2019 tuesday                              31
31.07.2019 wednesday                            31

31 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Today's week is `30`, so - if you uncomment the `where` clause (line #10), you'll get only this week:

```
SQL> l10
 10* --where to_char(datum, 'iw') = to_char(sysdate, 'iw')
SQL> c/--//
 10* where to_char(datum, 'iw') = to_char(sysdate, 'iw')
SQL> /

DATUM      DAY                                  WE
---------- ------------------------------------ --
22.07.2019 monday                               30
23.07.2019 tuesday                              30
24.07.2019 wednesday                            30
25.07.2019 thursday                             30
26.07.2019 friday                               30
27.07.2019 saturday                             30
28.07.2019 sunday                               30

7 rows selected.

SQL>
```

That's what you should have done (see the last line); also, you won't need two nested aggregate functions any more - `count` should be enough. Besides, you'd get `ORA-00978: nested group function without GROUP BY` if you keep nested aggregates without the `group by` clause; yes, you could keep it, but why? No need for it.

```
select 'TOTAL' label, 
       count(report_date) value 
from data 
where status = 'Open' 
  and managed_by = 'Internal' 
  and manager = 'Vinod' 
  and second_level_manager = 'Kumar' 
  --
  and to_char(report_date, 'iw') = to_char(sysdate, 'iw')      --> this
```